# how to configure Jitsi-meet recording?

Tags: java, ubuntu, webrtc, recording, jitsi

is there any site that would provide some insight to how to configure jitsi-meet recording functionality , I have tried to follow

https://github.com/jitsi/jibri

but I could not get it working is there any other step to follow ??

after trying to configure jirecon [ instead of jibri , new error appeared ]

------------------------- Google Chrome Log :

```
paltel:9 (TIME) index.html loaded:   111.98500000000001
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/RTCBrowserType.js] <Array.r>:  This appears to be Chrome, ver: 60
deprecation.js:59 DEPRECATED JS - Cookie has been deprecated since 5.8.0 and will be removed in a future release. Use cookie instead.   
     at assign (<anonymous>)
a @ deprecation.js:59
Logger.js:125 [react/index.web.js] <HTMLDocument.<anonymous>>:  (TIME) document ready:   760
Logger.js:125 [modules/URL/ConferenceUrl.js] <new e>:  Stored original conference URL: https://avchat2.paltel.ps/paltel
Logger.js:125 [modules/URL/ConferenceUrl.js] <new e>:  Conference URL for invites: https://avchat2.paltel.ps/paltel
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/ScreenObtainer.js] <Object.init>:  Desktop sharing disabled
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/RTCUtils.js] <t.value>:  Get media constraints Object
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/strophe.jingle.js] <new t>:  Configured STUN servers:  Array(3)
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  Lip-sync enabled !
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe connecting:  930.2950000000001
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) Strophe connected:   1523.73
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/xmpp.js] <t.value>:  My Jabber ID: 4e2ed720-f2c0-4f77-9801-3987ca9e6d85@avchat2.paltel.ps/5c80c272-225d-4b7f-b9cc-2d88bb214d13
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/strophe.ping.js] <o.value>:  XMPP pings will be sent every 10000 ms
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/RTCUtils.js] <>:  onUserMediaSuccess
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <>:  initialized with %s local tracks 2
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <new t>:  Joined MUC as paltel@conference.avchat2.paltel.ps/4e2ed720
Logger.js:125 [modules/connectivity/ParticipantConnectionStatus.js] <new e>:  RtcMuteTimeout set to: 2000
Logger.js:125 [modules/statistics/AvgRTPStatsReporter.js] <new e>:  Avg RTP stats will be calculated every 15 samples
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <new r>:  backToP2PDelay: 5
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <r._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no JVB JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <r._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no P2P JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <r._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no JVB JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <r._doReplaceTrack>:  _doReplaceTrack - no P2P JingleSession
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.setFocusUserJid>:  Focus jid set to:  undefined
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.createConferenceIq>:  Session ID: b25090d0-1e0c-4500-8437-b659150de78c machine UID: af23cedd523831129cd9220ccf920b09
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i._allocateConferenceFocusError>:  Session expired! - removing
Logger.js:125 [JitsiMeetJS.js] <Object.getGlobalOnErrorHandler>:  UnhandledError: null Script: null Line: null Column: null StackTrace:  Error: Focus error, retry after 1000
    at i._allocateConferenceFocusError (moderator.js:407)
    at moderator.js:339
    at u.Handler.handler (strophe.js:2735)
    at u.Handler.run (strophe.js:2013)
    at strophe.js:3110
    at Object.forEachChild (strophe.js:993)
    at u.Connection._dataRecv (strophe.js:3098)
    at e.Bosh._onRequestStateChange (strophe.js:4729)
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i._allocateConferenceFocusError>:  Focus error, retry after 1000 <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" type=​"error" to=​"4e2ed720-f2c0-4f77-9801-3987ca9e6d85@avchat2.paltel.ps/​5c80c272-225d-4b7f-b9cc-2d88bb214d13" from=​"focus.avchat2.paltel.ps" id=​"ac6f1bac-a302-4f9d-b473-4f3fadac3aca:​sendIQ">​…​</iq>​
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.setFocusUserJid>:  Focus jid set to:  undefined
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.createConferenceIq>:  Session ID: null machine UID: af23cedd523831129cd9220ccf920b09
Logger.js:125 [JitsiMeetJS.js] <Object.getGlobalOnErrorHandler>:  UnhandledError: null Script: null Line: null Column: null StackTrace:  Error: Focus error, retry after 2000
    at i._allocateConferenceFocusError (moderator.js:407)
    at moderator.js:339
    at u.Handler.handler (strophe.js:2735)
    at u.Handler.run (strophe.js:2013)
    at strophe.js:3110
    at Object.forEachChild (strophe.js:993)
    at u.Connection._dataRecv (strophe.js:3098)
    at e.Bosh._onRequestStateChange (strophe.js:4729)
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i._allocateConferenceFocusError>:  Focus error, retry after 2000 <iq xmlns=​"jabber:​client" type=​"error" to=​"4e2ed720-f2c0-4f77-9801-3987ca9e6d85@avchat2.paltel.ps/​5c80c272-225d-4b7f-b9cc-2d88bb214d13" from=​"focus.avchat2.paltel.ps" id=​"7f41c3d4-eec2-4d22-829f-92d25d47fa6f:​sendIQ">​…​</iq>​
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <e.value>:  CONFERENCE FAILED: conference.focusDisconnected focus.avchat2.paltel.ps 2
i @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.setFocusUserJid>:  Focus jid set to:  undefined
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.createConferenceIq>:  Session ID: null machine UID: af23cedd523831129cd9220ccf920b09
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.setFocusUserJid>:  Focus jid set to:  focus@auth.avchat2.paltel.ps
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.parseConfigOptions>:  Authentication enabled: true
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.parseConfigOptions>:  External authentication enabled: false
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.parseSessionId>:  Received sessionId:  ce445a55-ef1f-4574-a3dd-1d507e8055d4
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/moderator.js] <i.parseConfigOptions>:  Sip gateway enabled:  false
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <t.value>:  entered paltel@conference.avchat2.paltel.ps/focus Object
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <t.value>:  Ignore focus: paltel@conference.avchat2.paltel.ps/focus, real JID: focus@auth.avchat2.paltel.ps/focus516671488207362
Logger.js:125 [modules/version/ComponentsVersions.js] <>:  Got xmpp version: Prosody(0.9.10,Linux)
Logger.js:125 [modules/version/ComponentsVersions.js] <>:  Got focus version: JiCoFo(1.0.build.SVN,Linux)
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/recording.js] <r.handleJibriPresence>:  Handle jibri presence :  undefined
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <n.<anonymous>>:  Received recorder status change:  unavailable undefined
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <n.<anonymous>>:  My role changed, new role: none
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <t.value>:  (TIME) MUC joined:  4953.3
Logger.js:125 [modules/UI/videolayout/LargeVideoManager.js] <>:  hover in %s 4e2ed720
Logger.js:125 [conference.js] <n.<anonymous>>:  My role changed, new role: moderator
strophe.js:4843 XHR finished loading: POST "https://avchat2.paltel.ps/http-bind?room=paltel".
l @ strophe.js:4843
_processRequest @ strophe.js:4855
_throttledRequestHandler @ strophe.js:5013
_onIdle @ strophe.js:4633
_onIdle @ strophe.js:3718
setTimeout (async)
_send @ strophe.js:4972
send @ strophe.js:2653
sendIQ @ strophe.js:2757
value @ strophe.ping.js:67
(anonymous) @ strophe.ping.js:107
```

and as for the jirecon process log keeps repeating the following :

```
Aug 15, 2017 2:21:51 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader notifyConnectionError
SEVERE: Closes the connection temporary
stream:error (text)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:264)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:45)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:74)
```

Regards

Comment: you'll need to provide some more information about your setup (are you running your own jitsi meet deployment, for example?) and where you're running into problems (seeing any error messages?)

Comment: @bbaldino my setup is straight forward ubuntu 16 and as for the step I followd same as in the github section installation

Comment: no one is going to be able to help you if you don't provide (a lot) more information.

Comment: @bbaldino adding new logs and I am trying with jirecon for now instead of jibri since it is not salable and only one meeting can be recorder at a time